# How to send notification from one user to another

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing an app and I want one user to be able to send notification to another user. Is there another way to do that other than FCM?

Comment: That's how messaging works as well. You just build a notification when you receive the broadcast. FCM has that capability, keep digging into it.

Comment: What if I don't want to use FCM? what other options do I have?

Comment: There is generic solutions like Pubnub, Twilio and many other, they specialize in signaling services. Else you have to build your own backend infrastructure.

Comment: I am looking into serverScoket, but I'm confused with how to send messages between clients rather than client and a server ..

Comment: Before you send any message to anyone, you have to discovered the person you want to send the message to right? Using Pubnub SDK, they do that for you. All you have to do is pass the id of the user you want to send the notification to and wallah! all done.